# Bash script not working in Ubuntu in Windows 10

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is Ubuntu different from Linux on a Mac? Sorry if this is a basic question...I am new to this. I am trying to run a bash script that creates a .sh script out of some FASTQ files. This works in the terminal on a Mac OS. I am trying to run it on my Windows laptop and it ignores my escaping of #s and just states that several commands are not found. I have tried using `dos2unix` and double checked with `cat -A file.sh` but it hasn't helped.

The code I am trying to run takes all fastq files in a folder and creates a .sh file for SLURM job submissions using their file name (needed for my university's computer cluster, and I need to make 100+ job scripts).  So the Mac OS version is as follows:

```
for FILE in *fastq;    #change file type when needed (e.g., fasta, fastq, fastq.gz)
do echo -e \
\#\!/bin/bash \
\\n\#SBATCH --partition=nonpre  \# Partition \(job queue\) \
\\n\#SBATCH --requeue                 \# Return job to the queue if preempted \
\\n\#SBATCH --job-name=samples      \# Assign a short name to your job \
\\n\#SBATCH --nodes=1                 \# Number of nodes you require \
\\n\#SBATCH --ntasks=1                \# Total \# of tasks across all nodes \
\\n\#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=64        \# Cores per task \(\>1 if multithread tasks\) \
\\n\#SBATCH --mem=180000              \# Real memory \(RAM\) required \(MB\) \
\\n\#SBATCH --time=72:00:00           \# Total run time limit \(HH:MM:SS\) \
\\n\#SBATCH --output=slurm.%N.${FILE}.out  \# STDOUT output file \
\\n\#SBATCH --error=slurm.%N.${FILE}.err   \# STDERR output file \(optional\) \
\\n \
\\n\#ADD WHATEVER CODE YOU WANT HERE AS YOUR SLURM JOB SUBMISSION \
\\n \
\\nsacct --format=JobID,JobName,NTasks,NNodes,NCPUS,MaxRSS,AveRSS,AveCPU,Elapsed,ExitCode -j \$SLURM_JOBID \#this will get job run stats from SLURM\; use these to help designate memory of future submissions \
> ${FILE}.sh; 
done
```

When running this on Windows, I get:

```
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 13: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 14: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 16: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 18: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 20: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 22: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 24: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 26: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 28: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 30: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 32: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 35: \n: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 36: \n#ADD: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 39: \n: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 40: \nsacct: command not found
```

Any help would be appreciated, and some explanation on what the difference is between Ubuntu on Windows vs. the Terminal on Mac. I've tried researching this but I keep finding suggested code with no explanation or it isn't particularly my issue. Thank you!

Edit: I tried running `chmod +x script.sh` and I will get the above errors. Am I running 'echo' wrong? Even running:
'for FILE in *fastq;
do
echo -e
hello;
done'
says `Command 'hello' not found`

Edit: Running 'bash file.sh' yields the following:
`bash file.sh` yields the following (for each of the 5 .fastq files in my directoy):

```
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 8: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 9: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 11: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 13: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 15: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 17: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 19: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 21: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 23: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 25: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 27: \n#SBATCH: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 30: \n: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 31: \n#ADD: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 34: \n: command not found
Slurm_Generator.sh: line 35: \nsacct: command not found
```

If I run `cat -A file.sh` I see a `$` at the end of each line. Even if I get rid of these, I get the same result as above.
Running `ls -al script.sh` gived: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 cerberus cerberus 1209 Jun 16 00:17 Slurm_Generator.sh`

Edit:
I changed my script to:

```
#! /bin/bash
for FILE in *fastq;    #change file type when needed (e.g., fasta, fastq, fastq.gz)
do echo -e \
"
#\!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=nonpre  # Partition (job queue)
#SBATCH --requeue              # Return job to the queue if preempted
#SBATCH --job-name=samples     # Assign a short name to your job
#SBATCH --nodes=1              # Number of nodes you require
#SBATCH --ntasks=1             # Total # of tasks across all nodes
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=64 # Cores per task (>1 if multithread tasks)
#SBATCH --mem=180000           # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)
#SBATCH --time=72:00:00        # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --output=slurm.%N.${FILE}.out # STDOUT output file
#SBATCH --error=slurm.%N.${FILE}.err  # STDERR output file (optional)

#ADD WHATEVER CODE YOU WANT HERE AS YOUR SLURM JOB SUBMISSION \

sacct --format=JobID,JobName,NTasks,NNodes,NCPUS,MaxRSS,AveRSS,AveCPU,Elapsed,ExitCode -j \$SLURM_JOBID \#this will get job run stats from SLURM\; use these to help designate memory of future subm$" \
> ${FILE}.sh;
done
```

My new output is the following (which is much better):

```
#\!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=nonpre  # Partition (job queue)
#SBATCH --requeue           # Return job to the queue if preempted
#SBATCH --job-name=samples      # Assign a short name to your job
#SBATCH --nodes=1                 # Number of nodes you require
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                # Total # of tasks across all nodes
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=64 # Cores per task (>1 if multithread tasks)
#SBATCH --mem=180000              # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)
#SBATCH --time=72:00:00           # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --output=slurm.%N.Sample1.fastq.out  # STDOUT output file
#SBATCH --error=slurm.%N.Sample1.fastq.er  # STDERR output file (optional)


#ADD WHATEVER CODE YOU WANT HERE AS YOUR SLURM JOB SUBMISSION

sacct --format=JobID,JobName,NTasks,NNodes,NCPUS,MaxRSS,AveRSS,AveCPU,Elapsed,ExitCode -j $SLURM_JOBID \#this will get job run stats from SLURM\; use these to help designate memory of future submissions
```

The only issue I am running into is that while it prints this out for each .fastq file, which is what I want, the resulting .sh files that it writes out are blank. So it is not recognizing the `> ${File}.sh` part of the script.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Maybe `/bin/bash` is not in your Ubuntu terminal  path. You can check this by `env` command. Try adding `#! /bin/bash` to the very beginning of the script. Save it and execute again.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: @Karlom Unfortunately that didn't work. I tried `#! /bin/bash` as well as `#! /bin/sh` and I am able to call on `bash` from my path.

Comment: How are you trying to run the script? What error do you get? Perhaps you have not permission to execute that particular file? try `chmod +x file.sh` and if it was fine then run `bash file.sh` and if you still get error, post that to your question.

Comment: @Karlom I tried but it yielded the same result. Am I running echo wrong? Is there a different syntax in Ubuntu for Windows compared to a Mac? I have tried using it by echoing the text with and without quotes but it just thinks that whatever comes after `echo` is a command instead of text.

Comment: @Justin, Ubuntu as a virtual machine on Windows is not different from stand alone Ubuntu. To see what is wrong, in Ubuntu shell terminal, go to the directory in which the `file.sh` is located, then run `bash file.sh` and copy here the error that you receive. Also it helps if you post the output of `ls -al file.sh` while you are in the terminal in the path where file.sh resides.

Comment: @Karlom I just posted the results of all of that; apologies if any of this is info I should have already given!

Comment: The scrpit says `SBATCH: command not found`. So apparently you are trying to run a Windows script on Linux and it can not find that command. Please note that running `dos2unix` does not autmatically make your Windows script executable in Linux.

Comment: Yes, but SBATCH should be commented out, shouldn't it? using `echo -e` would make it so that the `\\n` and `\#` make new lines and get commented out respectively, right? Or is my syntax wrong? It works fine when I do this in a Mac Terminal. I just can't figure out where my script is wrong.

Comment: @Karlom You can also check with `which bash`. In ubuntu, wsl or no, this should be sufficient, I would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had to add a `\` before the `> ${File}.sh`. So the answer is:

```
#! /bin/bash
for FILE in *fastq;    #change file type when needed (e.g., fasta, fastq, fastq.gz)
do echo -e \
"
#\!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=nonpre  # Partition (job queue)
#SBATCH --requeue              # Return job to the queue if preempted
#SBATCH --job-name=samples     # Assign a short name to your job
#SBATCH --nodes=1              # Number of nodes you require
#SBATCH --ntasks=1             # Total # of tasks across all nodes
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=64 # Cores per task (>1 if multithread tasks)
#SBATCH --mem=180000           # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)
#SBATCH --time=72:00:00        # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --output=slurm.%N.${FILE}.out # STDOUT output file
#SBATCH --error=slurm.%N.${FILE}.err  # STDERR output file (optional)

#ADD WHATEVER CODE YOU WANT HERE AS YOUR SLURM JOB SUBMISSION \

sacct --format=JobID,JobName,NTasks,NNodes,NCPUS,MaxRSS,AveRSS,AveCPU,Elapsed,ExitCode -j \$SLURM_JOBID \#this will get job run stats from SLURM\; use these to help designate memory of future subm$" \
> ${FILE}.sh;
done
```

Comment: Good to hear you got it resolved.  Please remember to "Accept" your answer so that this question gets marked as resolved.  Unresolved questions get auto-bumped months or years later in an effort to try to solicit answers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use heredoc instead:

```
for FILE in *fastq; #change file type when needed (e.g., fasta, fastq, fastq.gz)
do

cat <<-EOF > ${FILE}.sh
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --partition=nonpre             # Partition (job queue)
#SBATCH --requeue                      # Return job to the queue if preempted
#SBATCH --job-name=samples             # Assign a short name to your job
#SBATCH --nodes=1                      # Number of nodes you require
#SBATCH --ntasks=1                     # Total # of tasks across all nodes
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=64             # Cores per task (>1 if multithread tasks)
#SBATCH --mem=180000                   # Real memory (RAM) required (MB)
#SBATCH --time=72:00:00                # Total run time limit (HH:MM:SS)
#SBATCH --output=slurm.%N.${FILE}.out  # STDOUT output file
#SBATCH --error=slurm.%N.${FILE}.err   # STDERR output file (optional)

#ADD WHATEVER CODE YOU WANT HERE AS YOUR SLURM JOB SUBMISSION

nsacct --format=JobID,JobName,NTasks,NNodes,NCPUS,MaxRSS,AveRSS,AveCPU,Elapsed,ExitCode -j \$SLURM_JOBID #this will get job run stats from SLURM; use these to help designate memory of future submissions
EOF

done
```